# OpenACC Compiling with AMD GPUs

Tags: c++, openacc, pgi, amd-gpu, pgi-accelerator

I am having trouble to compile it with AMD Radeon R7 M360. I have compiled it with multi-core as shown below, but can anybody please tell me how to compile it with GPU, I have tried `-ta=amd64/radeon` but none of it works. You can see code in this image. I compiled it with

```
pgc++ -V -Minfo=accel -acc -ta=multicore sum.cpp -o /home/fawad/Desktop/sum
```

[image]

main:

```
 7, Generating Multicore code
      9, #pragma acc loop gang
  7, Generating reduction(+:sum)
 10, Loop is parallelizable
```

I need someone to guide me how to compile with AMD. I am using the PGI Compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a variety of business and technical reasons, support for Radeon GPUs was removed from the PGI compilers on both Linux and Windows platforms starting with the PGI 17.1 release.

Answer (score 2):

Use PGI 16, check your card with  pgaccelinfo. My card is a hawaii archtecture so the target flag is:
-ta=radeon:hawaii

ex: pgc++ -V -Minfo=accel -acc -ta=radeon:hawaii,nollvm